# What do you call a person who eats products to test their quality?

Tags: word-request

Is there a word for it? There's the term food taster, but it seems it's used for people who test food for poison. I am talking more about people who taste food for big food companies, like a candy factory or a refrigerated meal factory.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In the U.S., we often call such a person a "taste tester". From [vocabulary.com](https://www.vocabulary.com/dictionary/taste-tester):

> someone who samples food or drink for its quality

From [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Blind_taste_test):

> taste tests are sometimes used as a tool by companies to develop their brand or new products